# SwiperJs and React not showing elements when Global "overflow-x: hidden" style applied

Tags: css, reactjs, overflow, swiper.js

I am using the Swiper.js package in a react app to make a simple carousel slider. My app has a global setting for `overflow-x: hidden` which I need and for some reason its causing the Swiper to only render the first image.

I have ensured `overflow: visible` on all affected elements but this has not changed it. I have tried a the most basic example as well and same issue.

I have tried previous versions but then got module import errors so just hoping someone has an answer for me. Brain is wrecked over this:(

I just want a simple image carousel using the swipe.js package.

Here is the code and a gif to better show the problem:

[image]

```
import React from "react";
import "./projectslider.scss";
import { Swiper, SwiperSlide } from "swiper/react";
import { Navigation, Thumbs } from "swiper";
import "swiper/css";
import "swiper/css/navigation";
import "swiper/css/thumbs";

function ProjectsSlider(props) {
  return (
    <>
      <div className="sliderProjects">
        <Swiper
          loop={false}
          spaceBetween={10}
          navigation={true}
          modules={[Navigation, Thumbs]}
          grabCursor={true}
          className="projectsSlider"
        >
          {props.images.map((item, index) => (
            <SwiperSlide key={index} className="swiperSlide">
              <img src={item} alt="slider images"></img>
            </SwiperSlide>
          ))}
        </Swiper>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}

export default ProjectsSlider;
```

CSS:

```
.sliderProjects {
  width: 70%;
  height: 70%;
  overflow: visible;

  .projectSlider {
    overflow: visible;
    width: 90%;
    height: 60%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;

    .swiperSlide {
      overflow: visible;

      img {
        overflow: visible;
        height: 20vh;
        width: 20wh;
      }
    }
  }
}
```